# GridView padding, verticalSpacing & horizontalSpacing just won't decrease

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview

I'm trying to create a grid of buttons. To show the dividers of a `GridLayout`, I have set the background of my `GridLayout` with color black & I have then tried placing my button. I am the getting dividers in the grid, but for some reason I cannot control their thickness.

I have tried setting the `verticalSpacing` and `horizontalSpacing` as low as 0.1, but still no use. It just won't decrease and I end up getting the following

[image]

Following is my **content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="accordiontry.juspay.accordiontry.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing=".05dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0.1dp">
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Following is the layout for the button, **cell_layout.xml**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Following is the custom grid adapter, **GridAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by stpl on 27/7/16.
 */
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String[] names;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, String[] names)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        View cell;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_layout,null);
            Button btn = (Button) cell.findViewById(R.id.button);
            btn.setText("BUTTON "+ names[i]);


        return  cell;

    }
}
```

And finally, following is my **MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GridView gridView;
    private final int NumOfCol = 2;
    private final int NumOfRows = 2;

    private String[] names = {"BUTTON1", "BUTTON2", "BUTTON3", "BUTTON4"};

    private GridAdapter gridAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        init();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void init()
    {
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, names);

        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

    }



}
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong. Please help.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons typically have their own built-in margin that comes from the drawable used as the button background.

One way to fix this is to specify a negative value for the margin:

```
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="-2dp" />
```

A better way is to create a drawable for the button that doesn't have any margin defined and use that for your button background.  For example, here is a button background drawable from the appcompat library (this one is pre-Lollipop and doesn't show the ripple):

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:insetLeft="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
       android:insetTop="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material"
       android:insetRight="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
       android:insetBottom="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/abc_control_corner_material" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <padding android:left="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
                 android:top="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material"
                 android:right="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
                 android:bottom="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

Those insets are the part which is giving you grief.  Just define another drawable for your button background with no insets.